# SQL Server Slowest Query is NULL

Tags: performance, query-performance, sql-server-2016

I am looking at both the SQL Server expensive queries report and the query below, but both are showing this mysterious `NULL` query as the slowest query on my server.

**Is there any way I can find out more about this `NULL` query and why it might be so slow?**

Is this some internal query? It doesn't seem like this should be showing up in the report if so.

[image]

This is the query which is also showing `NULL` as the slowest query on my server:

```
select 
    r.session_id,
    r.status,
    r.command,
    r.cpu_time,
    r.total_elapsed_time,
    t.text
from 
    sys.dm_exec_requests as r
cross apply 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) as t
```

[image]

How can I find out what this query is and why it's so slow?

Comment: That's a system session. `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(37);` might give a clue what it's doing, but since it's a _background_ task I'm not sure what you could possibly do to tune it... if you're just randomly checking `dm_exec_requests` you should probably limit it to non-system sessions (join to `sys.dm_exec_sessions` where `is_user_process = 1`). Why it's not filtered out of the report, no idea, I tend to not use built-in reports because I (and vendors) build much better versions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The response is "No Event" when executing `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(37);`.  When I join and filter on `is_user_process = 1` the query disappears from the results as you'd implied from its being a system session.  So, is it typical to see this `NULL` query in the expensive queries report?  I don't recall seeing it on other servers so I thought it might be an issue of some sort.  We are experiencing intermittent slowness on the server so I am trying to identify the root cause.

Comment: `So, is it typical to see this NULL query in the expensive queries report?` I don't know. Like I said, I don't use those reports for monitoring.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Gotcha - well since this is a red herring please feel free to post your answer of "That's a system session" and I will accept.  Otherwise, I can close this question as too being too localized.  Also, if there are any tools or queries which you may recommend to isolate intermittent poor performance on SQL Server 2016, you are certainly welcome to share!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a system session.

`DBCC INPUTBUFFER(37);` might give a clue what it's doing, or `CROSS APPLY` with  [`sys.dm_exec_input_buffer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-input-buffer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but you might not be able to understand any more about what it's doing. Since it's a *background* task, it is unlikely to be a cause for any other perceived slowness but, being internal, I'm not sure what you could possibly do to tune it anyway...

If you're just randomly checking `dm_exec_requests` you should probably limit it to non-system sessions (join to `sys.dm_exec_sessions` where `is_user_process = 1`). Why it's not filtered out of the report, I have no no idea, I tend to not use built-in reports because I (and vendors) build much better versions.

Comment: For these system tasks, the `command` column in `sys.dm_exec_requests` is sometimes also helpful, especially when input buffer isn't.